# Use two criteria for counting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, counting

This is how my data looks in Excel:........................The results would look like this:

[image] ....................................................[image]

I would like to calculate instances when 'a' in one row is followed by 'b' in the next row.

Can someone help me how to write a code for this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

in cell b5 type:

```
=If(And(A5="a",A6="b"),1,"")
```

then drag it down the column

Comment: @ Scott Holtzman thanks for  answering but When I try to use this formula it gives blank cell. Do you have an idea why it would not be working.Thanks